# jQuery cross domain request response headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, response-headers

I am making cross domain ajax requests with html data type.
They work OK as I include

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

in the response from the server. Problem is I need to get certain headers from the server's response and whatever I do, response headers apart from "content type" return null.

jQuery does the request, retrieves the response including headers (I can see it from the traffic) but it doesn't parse it.

I have tried using

```
crossDomain: true
```

It didn't help. Here is the sample response from the server.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:514
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8 
X-MYRESPONSEHEADER:1
```

If requesting and responding document are on same server

```
 success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        totalRows = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-MYRESPONSEHEADER");
```

works fine. I have also tried to assign $.ajax to a variable like

```
var jQxhr = $.ajax(.....
```

I don't see why it wouldn't be parsed since jQuery actually makes the request and gets the response

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

### Update or dragon's comment

Headers sent to request

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-MYRESPONSEHEADER
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
X-MYRESPONSEHEADER: 24
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 11:34:21 GMT
```

Content-Length: 514

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another CORS-specific header in the server response, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. In this case,

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-MYRESPONSEHEADER
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: it didn't work for me. do you think i need to assign $.ajax to a variable?

Comment: Is your [HTTP OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Preflighted_requests) returning the appropriate Access-Control headers?

Comment: @nLL Could you add the full request/response headers for each of the two requests made? First request is OPTIONS and second is GET/POST.

Comment: I don't do any OPTIONS request manually and don;t see jQuery doing it. Is it part of the process? If so how would jQuery know about it

Comment: It is a part of the process, and the browsers do it in certain cases before making cross-domain calls, as per the specifications. Please note that jQuery doesn't make this call -- browsers do. For more, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Preflighted_requests

Comment: Im testing it on Chrome and don;t see any request from browser. Anyways I'll have to dig in deeper. Thanks for your time

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Headers only controls which request headers can be sent. It doesn't influence response headers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using aws s3 (and I assume this is applicable otherwise), the problem is possibly a missing CORS configuration tag.  I ran in to a similar problem with  missing.  Here's my completed configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>*</ExposeHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

AllowedHeader sets the **Access-Control-Request-Headers** header, and ExposeHeader sets **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** header, without which the browser wont allow javascript to use the returned headers.

Comment: S3 gives error: ExposeHeader "*" contains wildcard. We currently do not support wildcard for ExposeHeader.

Comment: Same problem -- didn't work with wildcard. In my case though I just needed the browser to expose the Location header and this answer worked with the header explicitly defined.

Answer (score 2):

To read headers other than content-type in the server's response, the server must supply `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, eg:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-MYRESPONSEHEADER
```

@dragon's answer mentions`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` which only controls which headers the client can send when making a request to the server.

Useful CORS tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

Here is configuration that worked for me. I've put it in java Filter filter method. Some headers need to be send only with preflight request (method = "OPTIONS"), there is no need to send them every time.

Please notice that for "Authorization" header the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" is also required.

```
 HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
 resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://your_domain:your_port");
 resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
 if (((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
       resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
      resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
      return;
  }
```